# Embedding Python into C

Tags: python, c, windows

Win7 x64, Python3.3 32bit, Visual Studio 2010/2012 (same behavior). The following code compiles and runs just fine (i.e. prints current date):

```
extern "C"{ // not having it doesn't make any difference either
#include <Python.h>
}

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
        "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

while this here fails with a MessageBox saying `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005). Click OK to close the application.` before `main` executed (so no breakpoint possible).

```
extern "C"{ // not having it doesn't make any difference either
#include <Python.h>
}

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *p = PyUnicode_FromString("test");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with that, and it works for me, albeit on Linux. Try rebuilding from clean.

Comment: @Aya I even created a completely new solution with just that code in it without any help. Obviously the usual `clean solution; rebuild solution` stuff too. No idea what else I could try there..

Comment: If you've done a debug build, it might be looking for a `python33_d.dll` which doesn't exist. Try a release build. There are other possibilities if you're linking with a `python33.lib` which you didn't build yourself. I found it to be most reliable if you build your own copy of `python33.lib` and `python33.dll`, and link against those.

Comment: @Aya Same problem for release build (actually for the debug build I just undef _DEBUG before including the python header to avoid exactly that problem). Anyway if it can't find the dll it just tells me that it can't find it, but not this kind of error.

Comment: If it's a 64-bit OS, but you're linking to a 32-bit Python, maybe you have to build a 32-bit binary? I dunno. I always built my own copy of Python for embedding purposes and used the same build settings for building the embedding binary, and never had any major issues.

Comment: @Aya Building a 32bit binary too, so the bitness is no problem. And since I only call c functions shouldn't it not matter if it's the same compiler/whatever with which the dll was written?

Comment: @Ignacio I hope [this](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/6S38Cfj/0/blob?download) works, looks pretty normal to me, but I must admit I've not much experience with that stuzff.

Comment: I can't read that file. Go through the DLL imports and see if all the function imports resolve.

Comment: @Voo Possibly. There are different [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which might affect it.

Comment: @Ignacio Ok looked at it in more detail. The broken one has `python33.dll` only in the sub-hierarchy for `python3.dll` (with all 3 calls in it and can't bind `PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString`), while the working one only has Init/Finalize under Python3.dll, but an extra entry for python3.dll for `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags` (which resolves correctly). Hope that makes somewhat sense, although I've no idea what that means or how I'd fix it..

Comment: @Ignacio Pictures help probably more :) [broken](http://13l.imghost.us/kC/broken.png); [working](http://13l.imghost.us/3Y/working.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems to have been the following: I was linking with `python3.lib` but since the string functions were completely overworked with Python3.3 there seemed to have been some problem with correctly linking them. (can't really explain why this would be so, since `PyUnicode_FromString` existed obviously in earlier versions of python3 too).

Why I couldn't get a useful error message about that fact is also beyond me, but there we go: linking against `python33.lib` solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be for 2 reasons, but I'm pretty sure its this one:

http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/unicode.html

You need to null terminate y our constant string "test" by making it "test\0".   If that doesn't work, it might have to do with the fact that c files are ansi and not utf8.

Comment: String literals have an implicit NUL at the end, and those characters are encoded the same way in UTF-8 and "ANSI".

Comment: Maybe in python, but there is no implicit NULL attached to C strings.

Comment: ["... a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals."](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.5.html)

Comment: In C11, not C99, and C11 isn't even fully supported yet by any compiler/ who knows if there's a null termination byte appended automatically?

Comment: ["After any concatenation, a null byte \0 is
appended to the string so that programs that scan the string can find its end."](http://books.google.ca/books/about/The_C_Programming_Language.html?id=161QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: 1: that page doesn't even say that.  2: concatenation is named so in the string library, which is not part of the c standard lib.

Comment: 1. That book does. 2. String literal concatenation is performed by the compiler.

Comment: 1. Where on that page/where in the book.  I've got it right next to me. 2: String literal concatenation is not done in C99 by the compiler, and may not be done in any compiler since C11 hasn't been fully implemented by any compiler.

Comment: I don't think there was a single C compiler ever (and C89 certainly had that included as well) that didn't specify that `char *foo = "foo"` will be null terminated. Otherwise `printf("Hello World\n")` would be horribly broken..

Comment: 1. A.2.6, "String Literals" 2. String literal concatenation has been performed by the compiler ever since ANSI C was ratified.

Answer (score 0):

Your broken program is linking against a build of Python that uses UCS-2 as the internal `unicode` representation, but the installed Python uses UCS-4, and therefore the `PyUnicodeUCS2_*` imports can't be resolved. You'll need to link against the UCS-4 build instead.